# Why doesn't the <div> move?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a code that's suppose to move a `<div>` from 94% left to, aproximetly, 4% left, but it doesn't seem to work. I believe the flaw is in the CSS part of the code, because the console reports no errors.

HTML:

```
<body id="page_body">
    <div class="header_wrap">
        <div class="header_main_title">
            <h1>Text</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="scroll" class="scroll_button"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="leftslide"></div>
        <div class="rightslide"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    /*width: 2960px;*/
    width: 1600px;
    height: 710px;
}

div.leftslide {
    float: left;
    width: 1500px;
    background: url("1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 790px;
}

div.rightslide {
    position: fixed;
    left: 94%;
    width: 1460px;
    background: url("1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 790px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    $('.rightslide').animate({left: "100%"});
});
```

**JSFIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/AFysR/

Comment: Is it a typo that you're setting left to 100% instead of 4% in the code?

Comment: Why not set left: 4%? [http://jsfiddle.net/4s8Vx/](http://jsfiddle.net/4s8Vx/)

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you expect to happen? Is `.rightslide` the div you're hoping to move? What do you expect the end position of it to be? Can you reproduce that with CSS? And what's happening now that you view as "not working"?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Had major problems with my internet connection. 
the .leftslide div should be 100% visible, while the .rightslide div should be connected to it on the right side with only 4-6% visible. When you press the button, the .leftslide moves to the left, revealing the .rightslide completely, and leaving only 4-6% of the .leftslide visible. I hope you grasp the concept.

Comment: @Robert your fiddle does exactly what I need. Well, except the fact that I need to move the .leftslide also. But nevertheless, I can't seem to get it working. I match the code and it is 100% same as in the fiddle. Somehow, it doesn't work. No errors in the console, and no movement of the div.

Comment: okay, funny thing is, when I copy the code completely to jsFiddle, it runs great, but when I run it on my PC, it doesn't... I repeat myself: no errors are seen in the console. I had them when I placed the jquery link below the javascript link, but I changed their position so no more errors.

Comment: Did my solution work for you, or are you still running into issues?

Answer (score 2):

I shouldn't be getting downvoted. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NmcZj/

```
$('#scroll').click(function() {
$('.rightslide').animate({left: "-=100%"});
});
```

That should do it. (the difference is the  "-=")

Answer (score 0):

Fixed everything by changing:

```
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    $('.rightslide').animate({left: '4%'});
});
```

**TO:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#scroll').click(function() {
    $('.rightslide').animate({left: '4%'});
});
});
```